# Random Link PHP with Time

Tags: php, random, time, hyperlink

I have this code on stackoverflow:

```
    <?php
$links = array(array('url' => 'http://google.com', 'name'=>'google'),
               array('url' => 'http://hotmail.com', 'name' => 'hotmail'),
               array('url' => 'http://hawkee.com', 'name' => 'Hawkee'));
$num = array_rand($links);
$item = $links[$num];

printf('<a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a>', $item['url'], $item['name'], $item['name']);
?>
```

This code displays a random link.
I want to add time to each link, 24 hours after switching to the next link 1, after 24h switch to link 2 and repeat the same function for link 3.

¿ how could I do that process ?

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: You want it to randomly switch once a day every day? Per user, per site?

Comment: @user3185638 are you used a database to register these links and the date/time when exposed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the current unix timestamp to calculate the index of the link to display.

```
$item = $links[time()/86400 % 3];
```

86400 is the number of seconds in a day.

Comment: Thank you very much for the code, worked perfectly,  can set the time randomly ?

I want to be changed in 2 days after 4 days after 3 and repeat this sequence.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, get the day of year and use modulo to decide which link should be shown. This way it will be rotated every 3 days. See [date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
$links = array(array('url' => 'http://google.com', 'name'=>'google'),
               array('url' => 'http://hotmail.com', 'name' => 'hotmail'),
               array('url' => 'http://hawkee.com', 'name' => 'Hawkee'));
//$num = array_rand($links);
$num = intval(date('z'))%3 // this will return 0,1,2 based on which day we are currently
$item = $links[$num];

printf('<a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a>', $item['url'], $item['name'], $item['name']);
```

Answer (score 0):

use php cron job for create php time events look example [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/)